# refresh <head> container of the website using ajax

Tags: ajax

Is there a way to refresh only a part of a website using ajax or a similar technique? The visitor must not notice the refresh.

What I want to do is refresh the `<head></head>` container of a website only one time after the website has been fully loaded using ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, you can modify `<head>` after the page has loaded. This can be used to quietly load remote scripts, or similar actions.

Without more specifics of what you're trying to do, here's some generic example code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Send your ajax request, with success callback ajaxCallback
}

function ajaxCallback(response) {
    //Parse response to create HTML tags you want inserted into <head>
    var newHTML = response.newHTML;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newHTML);
    //If you want to completely replace the contents of <head>,
    //you can use .innerHTML instead of .appendChild
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to load remote scripts. I only want to refresh the head once the page has loaded. Can you modify this code only to do that?

Comment: can you please help me with it?